# T4 template for add service reference

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio, wcf-data-services, t4

I would like create interfaces for my auto generated client proxies, i want to expose these interfaces outside of my library and keep the implementation internal - currently the generated classes are public even though i set them to be internal on the add service reference dialog.

I have looked into T4 templates but have not been able to find any information on how to do this.

Does anyone have any idea how i can do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the T4 template used by the WCF Dataservices Team to generate their proxy classes may get you started in writing your own T4 template to generate your code tweaks, in my case it did.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2012/01/19/announcing-odata-t4-for-c-preview-1.aspx